# TextField works differently with key 'a' when rendered using Menu

Tags: reactjs, menu, material-ui, textfield

I have this code (component MyText) in my react application:

```
  public render(): JSX.Element {  
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Box m={4}>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="textSecondary">
            Write some text
          </Typography>
          <TextField
            value={this.state.text}
            size="small"
            fullWidth={true}
            onChange={(event): void => this.setState({ text: event.currentTarget.value }) }
          />
        </Box>
      </Fragment>
    );
```

The code is inside a Popover component. Then I have a Menu component with a MenuItem that opens the Popover. For some reason text input works differently when 'a' is pressed. All other characters work, but pressing 'a' loses focus from the TextField when key 'a' doesn't follow directly after some other key. Thus 'a' as the first letter doesn't work.

When the app is like this, I have the problem with TextField:

```
        <App>
          <Menu>
            <MenuItem>
              <MyPopover>
                <MyText>
                  {example code}
                </MyText>
              </MyPopover>
            </MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </App>
```

When I render like this, TextField works ok:

```
        <App>
          <Box>
              <MyPopover>
                <MyText>
                  {example code}
                </MyText>
              </MyPopover>
          </Box>
        </App>
```

Any ideas where to look for a bug?

Comment: I don't see anything overtly obvious. What version of React are you using? Can you create a *running* codesandbox with a minimal code example that reproduces this issue?

Comment: I tried to create a codesandbox example, but I can't reproduce the issue in a simplified example. This is what I came up with: https://vrmfq.csb.app/

In the example inputs work as expected. The example is 1:1 from MyComponent down. In my real application the AppBar has router props etc.

Comment: I modified the codesandbox example, but the example doesn't reproduce the bug.

However, I added <Link> components to <MyMenu> as there are in my real application. When I remove the router links from the real application's <MyMenu>, the bug disappears. I have no idea why.